# jQuery filter how can i link to second tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my page https://spdemosite.com/corstone/our-portfolio/ were jQuery filter is there to filter items.

My question is how can I land my user directly to USA, Korea or any other country from some other page.

So, Basically i want my user to land on USA when they click on USA link from some other page and vice versa.

Thanks.

Comment: Put a link on that other page ..?

Comment: Hello , Please add your code , show us what you did try. btw your link isn't working

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

I want to achieve something like this but i want #link when user click on other items.

Comment: you can use anchor tag for that, like <a href="your_path/USA">Click here for USA </a>

Comment: @BarLevin I am using WordPress theme and filter comes with the theme this is the URL were i have place the filter  https://spdemosite.com/corstone/our-portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL parameters something like `http://example.com?country=USA` and
`http://example.com?country=Korea` then in your javascript extract the value of `country` and display the section accordingly.

check this answer [how to get url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/how-to-get-url-parameter-using-jquery-or-plain-javascript)